# I have run into a Git Snafu

Tags: git, github

I forked from the wrong repository and made changes that I want to keep on my local machine. (I've staged, committed and pushed on this branch as well).

Well I deleted the remote repo and forked the correct one.

I need to know how I can push the changed on my local machine to this new forked repo.

Comment: Use `git remote set-url` to change the remote, and then `git push` again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new tracking branch for the remote branch on the forked repo you originally wanted to work on.
2. Use `git cherry-pick`, to cherry-pick each one of your commits, individually, from the branch they were made on, into your correct branch.

Comment: This approach sounds *incredibly* involved for something that doesn't seem to warrant it.

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Git, `cherry-pick` also supports multiple commits and treeish, which can save a lot of time if you need to cherry-pick large blocks of commits.

Comment: There's nothing particularly "involved" about using cherry-pick. Additionally, "wrong repo" does not necessarily mean a mirror of the real git repo. It could be a similar repo, with a similar branch, and fiddling with remote url, and doing a cowboy-style git push, is unlikely to result in anything productive.